# How to declare global variables in php codeigniter 3.1.9?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, global, declaration

I wrote a function with global variables, it works fine in normal run php but it does not execute in php codeigniter. Please check my code below and help me on how i should declare global variables in codeigniter 3.1.9

```
function getEmi($t)
{
    global $i, $upto, $totalint, $rate, $monthly, $payment_date, $arr, $_SESSION, $tp; 
    $i++;
    $r = $t*$rate; $p = round($monthly-$r); $e = round($t-$p);
    if ($upto <= 0){ return 0; }
    if ($upto == 2){ $_SESSION['tl'] = $e; }
    if ($upto == 1){ $p = $_SESSION['tl']; $e = round($t-$p); $monthly = round($p+$r); }
    $totalint = $totalint + $r; $tp = $tp+$monthly; $upto--;
    echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td>'; 
    $arrDate1 = explode('-', $arr[$i-1]);
    echo '<td>'.date("d-M-Y", mktime(0,0,0,$arrDate1[1],$arrDate1[2],$arrDate1[0])).'</td>';
    echo '<td>Rs.'.number_format(round($r)).'</td>';
    echo '<td>Rs.'.number_format($t).'</td>';
    echo '<td>Rs.'.number_format($p).'</td>';
    echo '<td>Rs.'.number_format($monthly).'</td>';
    echo '<td>Rs.'.number_format(round($e)).'</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';
    return getEmi($e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your Global Variables in Constant File
File PATH: \application\config\constants.php 

Or
You can add your Global Variables in Config File
File PATH: \application\config\config.php

```
define('ThemeColor', 'blue');//key and value
```

Now ThemeColor is your global variable you can use it in entire MVC pages, No need to write '$' before variable just use it as you wrote in define